# Google Actions & Auth0 Account Linking problems

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, auth0

I'm working on my smarthome application for Google Home. I use this library: https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs

For authentication I use Auth0 with Account Linking. This seems to work quiet well but the Bearer token in the Authorization header is malformated (it is not a valid JWT token).

e.g.: "authorization":"Bearer sIuaA9F2N9hn_aVIgVBAb2rcrpl1m8e5"

To validate the jwt-token I want to use jwks-rsa (https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/nodejs/01-authorization#validate-access-tokens)

So I tried to add the scope id_token in the Account Linking section but I don't receive the correct access token in the header.

So finally my question: How can I make my google application request the correct access token from Auth0?

UPDATE:

To login in I use email/password credentials from auth0.

[Account Linking Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byRdr.png)

```
this.app = smarthome({
  key: settings.smarthomeKey
});

this.app.onSync(async (body, headers) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(headers));
  return {...};
});
```

Headers received in the sync function:

```
{"x-real-ip":"xx.xxx.x.xxx","x-forwarded-for":"xx.xxx.x.xxx","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.localtunnel.me","x-forwarded-proto":"https","x-nginx-proxy":"true","connection":"close","content-length":"79","content-type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","google-assistant-api-version":"v1","authorization":"Bearer aIxaA9F2N9hn_aVAgVBSb2rcrpl1m8e5","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Cloud-Functions/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)","accept-encoding":"gzip,deflate,br"}
```

Comment: Are you using standard credentials for authentication before receiving the token? Or are you using Google as an identity provider?

Comment: Can you update your question to provide more information (screen shots with masked sensitive information, if necessary) about how you have configured both the Action and Auth0? What scopes are you currently requesting? What endpoints are you using?

Comment: Thx for your comments! I updated the question.

Comment: Your screenshot shows a standard Oauth account linking workflow. JWT are not relevant at this point, you need to exchange the token for an access token with the Oauth provider. It's a very well documented protocol and there are many libraries available to simplify the process. I recommend you read up on it a little before you proceed.

Comment: You won't get a JWT. You'll get an access token from Auth0. You can use their library to exchange that for a user id or an email, depending on the scopes you set in the Actions console.

Comment: @NickFelker So I have to exchange the token on every request?

Comment: Not necessarily, if you can locally cache the access token and associate with your server's content until it expires. But generally you'll need to make an additional call to exchange the token for something more useful.